# Hide MasterViewController in Master-Detail Application using Storyboard (XCode 4.2)

Tags: master-detail, xcode-storyboard

I have created new application using Master-Detail Templte with storyboard. I want to give user facility where they can Hide/Show Master View Controller in Landscape mode. I found few examples on net but none are using story board and Master-Detail template with Navigation Controller.

I have already implemented splitviewcontroller willHideViewController & willShowViewController which help me hide Master View Controller in Portrait mode. I am using below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of App Delegate to load views intially,

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
```

I would appriciate if you can point me right direction.

Thanks,
Tapan Desai

Answer (score 0):

The master view is presented in a popover and the popover can be used to control the visibility of the master.

So...follow these steps:

1)  Create a property to hold the popoverController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *pc;
```

2)  Capture the popoverController on the SplitViewController willHide delegate call

```
-(void) splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = @"Menu"; 
    id detailViewController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    [detailViewController setSplitViewBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
    self.pc = pc;  //poppver controller
}
```

3)  Finally just use the pc var to dismiss the popover

```
 if (self.pc) {
        [self.pc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
```